# How to interrupt a Gurobi model optimization in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, mathematical-optimization, gurobi, feasibility

I've seen one can set a time limit, node limit, etc. to stop a Gurobi model optmimization but those are parameters you can only set before running the optimization.

I want to know how to interrupt programatically a optimization without stopping the program calling the model (I'm programming in c#) because I want to try using the suboptimal variable values.

If it's of any use I'm running the model in separate threads than the program GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call Abort from a callback.  See examples/c#/callback_cs.cs for an example.

Comment: Thanks! For the record, here's a link to the callback_cs.cs file in the online Gurobi documentation. http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.1/example-tour/node81